# Resetting unique_ptr to an array of characters

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers

I'm porting an old C++ program to modern C++. The legacy program uses `new` and `delete` for dynamic memory allocation. I replaced `new` with `std::unique_ptr`, but I'm getting compilation error when I try to reset the `unique_ptr`.

Here is the striped down version of the program. *My aim is to get rid of all the naked `new`*.

```cpp
#include <memory>

enum class Types {
    ONE,
    TWO,
};

// based on type get buffer length
int get_buffer_len(Types type) {
    if(type == Types::ONE) return 10;
    else if(type == Types::TWO) return 20;
    else return 0;
}

int main() {
    Types type = Types::ONE;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> msg{};

    auto len = get_buffer_len(type);
    if(len > 0) {
        msg.reset(std::make_unique<char[]>(len));
    }

    // based on type get the actual message
    if(type == Types::ONE) {
        get_message(msg.get());
    }
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```cpp
error: no matching function for call to 'std::unique_ptr<char []>::reset(std::__detail::__unique_ptr_array_t<char []>)'
      |         msg.reset(std::make_unique<char[]>(len));
      |         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: [`reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) takes a pointer-to-instance/data, not another `std::unique_ptr`. The error message is thus self-explanatory. I think you want `msg = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);`

Comment: `msg = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);` should do the job

Comment: I recently upgraded some old code (C++/2e era) to C++17.  I replaced the `char* buffer = new char[sz];` buffers with `std::vector<std::byte> buffer(sz);`.  The change had ripple effects throughout the code, but was worth the extra effort.  (Also uncovered pre-existing bugs in the old code.)

Comment: Yes this could be another solution, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [`reset` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset), it takes a ptr to memory, not another unique ptr:

```
// members of the specialization unique_ptr<T[]>
template< class U >
void reset( U ptr ) noexcept;
```

This function is designed to allow you to `reset` a unique pointer and simultaneously capture memory that you intend to manage with said `unique_ptr`. What you are looking to do is assign an r-value `unique_ptr` to ann existing `unique_ptr` (`msg`), for which c++ also has an answer:

[`unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr&& r ) noexcept;`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D)

> Move assignment operator. Transfers ownership from r to *this as if by calling reset(r.release()) followed by an assignment of get_deleter() from std::forward(r.get_deleter()).

So you can instead just do:

```
msg = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);
```